# Realization of a Beta distribution function from a derived Exponential function

Tags: probability, distributions, exponential-distribution, beta-distribution

So we have a beta distribution Y∼Beta(1,β) and a random variable X which is given by the equation
X=−log(Y)
I found the cumulative distribution function of Y to be

[image]

Then I found the cdf of X

[image]

[image]

So X is distributed by an exponential distribution with parameters beta.

The question is, how do I make a realization of random variable Y from a realized value of X?

I let X = psi(Y)

[image]

Then

[image]

[image]

Intuitively, one would think to apply the inverse e^-x, but this result I got is actually the negative of the Fy onto the e^x + 1. Which way is correct?

Comment: If you have $X=-\log(Y)$ then you can generate $Y$ from $X$ by taking $Y=\exp(-X)$

Comment: Check the ["inverse transform sampling" simulation method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I understand the inverse transform sampling method, but isn't that only from a uniform distribution?